# I want to know about the MKMapView?

Tags: iphone

I am fresher.I don't have any idea how to use MKMapView in my application? Can anybody give me any beginner  source code which can give me an idea about the MKMapView.I am trying MKMapView from last 1 hour but my application is suddenly quitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have added MKMapView in Interface Builder but haven't added MapKit framework to your project. To add the framework, right click on Frameworks group in Xcode choose Add->Existing Frameworks and select MapKit.framework from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205

See, in particular, the "Related sample code" section.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the below link:
You will be able to understand the basics of adding Maps to your application.

http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial/#comment-5286

Comment: There is also a sample MapApp on this link.Hope it helps