# How to make second layer view with settings like in iphone "maps" app

Tags: iphone, user-interface, view, settings, maps

Hello i want to develop simple iPhone application with one button. And I want to have a list with settings like in "Maps" application on iPhone (see screenshot)

[image]

--
Have you got any advises to do it ?

Comment: I can not see screenshot. are you talking about that curl effect setting in app itself? or device settings.

Comment: http://www.teleportex.ru/tm/1.png

Comment: yes.. i mean that fun animation when you click on the right botton side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this previous SO question [How to make half curl animation in iPhone like the maps app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863049/how-to-make-half-curl-animation-in-iphone-like-the-maps-app)

This SO question will help you [iPhone SDK 4 "Half curl page transition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133644/iphone-sdk-4-half-curl-page-transition)

If you create a new `UIViewController`, set its `modalTransitionStyle` to [`UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl), and then `presentModalViewController:animated:` it, you'll get the desired "half curl page" effect.

Comment: Are there some tutorials? or open sources?

Comment: You can start here for basic info on map view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507048/i-want-to-know-about-the-mkmapview

Comment: Okey.. Thanks a lot I'll try tommorrow..
How should make right-bottom image ? and Is that image or not?

Comment: I think it will suit if u have button with an image. Pls accept and vote up the answers if it helped you

Comment: i have worked with MKMapKit. this time i want to have simple view with other background settings view.

Comment: You can create a view controller whose view contains the lower view. create it the way you want it and then use the modalTransitionStyle to get the effect on the button press